# Regular expression - Allow period('.') in the middle of the string but not at the end

Tags: regex

I am using a regular expression to allow and reject strings based on the criteria--

```
The expression used-
^([\w\.,'()@&-]|\s)*$

Allows-

exmple_
example(ggg)
exam.pl56e
exam.pl56e.hbhbh.
exampleghh. vgvj
example (bb)ste kklk ae
_example_
```

Currently, it allows adding period in the middle of the string as well as at the end.

I just want to reject string if the period is added at the end of the string but allow it to be added in the middle using the above regular expression

```
For example, reject-

Test.test1.
Example.
Test Test.
test@example.
exam.pl56e.hbhbh.
```

Comment: You may use `^[\w.,'()@&\s-]*$(?<!\.)`, or `^(?!.*\.$)[\w.,'()@&\s-]*$`. Note that `exam.pl56e.hbhbh.` will get rejected.

Comment: `/^[^.]+[.]?[^.]+$/` work? [demo](https://regex101.com/r/NBkidE/1/)

Comment: Glad [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51368317/3832970) worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) (you are entitled to upvoting after you reach 15 rep points).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a single character class in the pattern (merge `\s` with the previous character class) to simplify the pattern, and use either

```
^([\w.,'()@&\s-]*[\w,'()@&\s-])?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4lUmxz/1).

**Details**

- `^` -  start of string
- `([\w.,'()@&\s-]*[\w,'()@&\s-])?` - an optional sequence (if you want to match at least 1 char, remove `(` and `)?`) of:

  - `[\w.,'()@&\s-]*` - 0+ word, `.`, `,`, `'`, `(`, `)`, `@`, `&`, whitespace or hyphen chars
  - `[\w,'()@&\s-]` - a word, `,`, `'`, `(`, `)`, `@`, `&`, whitespace or hyphen chars (but no `.`!)
- `$` - end of string

Or, a lookbehind version:

```
^[\w.,'()@&\s-]*$(?<!\.)
```

It matches a string that only consists of the chars inside the character class, and after the end of string is matched, the lookbehind checks if the last char is a dot. If it is, the match is failed.

Or, a lookahead

```
^(?!.*\.$)[\w.,'()@&\s-]*$
```

Here, `(?!.*\.$)` checks if the string ends with `.` after any 0+ chars, and if it does, no match is returned. Else, the string is matched against the `[\w.,'()@&\s-]*` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify that the last character cannot be a period.

```
^([\w\.,'()@&-]|\s)*[^.]$
```

Comment: this might match things you would otherwise not want, Like `RedRover1`. This would not match in the original regex, but would here.

Answer (score 0):

A nice trick I've learned is to blacklist certain otherwise-allowed expressions by placing them on their own in an unmatched alternation in front of the matched one.

```
# sentences containing `foo` or `bar` but not the word `foobar`
^.*foobar.*$|(^.*foo.*$)|(^.*bar.*$)
```

This is admittedly a bit...*verbose* here:

```
^(?:[\w\.,'()@&-]|\s)*\.$|^([\w\.,'()@&-]|\s)*$
```

So it might be better to use a negative lookbehind

```
^([\w\.,'()@&-]|\s)*$(?<!\.)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negative lookahead `(?!`) to assert that what follows are not the characters in the character class repeated zero or more times ending with a dot at the end of the string.

[`^(?![\w\.,'()@&\s-]*\.$)[\w\.,'()@&\s-]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/1ivT2O/1)

Note that using the asterix `*` it matches zero or more times.